# Custom link ( '/' ) in subdirectory redirect to the home directory

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I change my wordpress installation to my subdirectory. 
But my custom link `/` in one menu item redirect to home directory.

Such as my parent domain is `maindomain.com` and my wordpress installation is in `maindomain.com/wordpress/site1`

Now when I click on the `site1` menu item which contain custom link `/` then it take me to the `maindomain.com` not in the `maindomain.com/wordpress/site1` .

I want it to take me `maindomain.com/wordpres/site1`

My .htaccess rule for `site1` is below

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/valley/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/valley/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**Note:** **I have no files in the `maindomain.com`**

Comment: That’s how relative URLs _work_. A leading slash refers to the domain root. If you don’t want this, then set the _correct_ URL in your link to begin with.

Comment: Yes, I know. But I thought, if there is any alternative.

Comment: Well you can redirect every request for `maindomain.com/` back into your WP directory, if you want … but then you won’t be able to use the main domain for anything else later.

Comment: Yes. I know. Thats why I was finding this alternative. 
Thanks for you time. I will fix the custom link in my subdomain. Thank :)